# reciprocal of logistic coefficient interpretation

Tags: logistic, interpretation

Suppose if a dependent variable is having a disease (1) and not having a disease (0). similarly , independent variable is smoking and not smoking. here , not smoking as reference group.
Again, if logistic coefficient of smoking is - 0.3.
odd ratio = exp (-0.3) = 0.74
Can we interpret it as , reciprocal of odd ratio= 1/0.74 = 1.34 ..
Smoker have 1.34 times odd of not having disease than non smoker. or
is it " Non smoker have 1.34 times odd of having disease than smoker"
is both interpretation correct or not ? I am just confused.

Comment: You really mean *negative* of the coefficient, not its reciprocal.  The coefficient will be negated when you reverse your coding: use 0 for having the disease and 1 for not.  Interpret the result accordingly.

Comment: is the changing sign of coefficient , reverses coding in dependent variables?

Comment: Yes.  The math is simple: recoding your responses converts any $y$ to $1-y.$  Thus,you are changing from a model of the form $E[Y\mid X]=h^{-1}(X\beta)$ to $E[1-Y\mid X]=1-E[Y\mid X] = 1 - h^{-1}(X\beta).$   The link function $h$ is the logit, which enjoys the symmetry $h(-z)=1-h(z).$  Thus, $E[Y\mid X] = h^{-1}(X(-\beta)),$ demonstrating that recoding simply negates the coefficients.  Consequently, the coefficient estimates are negated, too.

Comment: oh does it work in independent variables?

Comment: Yes, but it's a tiny bit more complicated.  In a model where $h(E[y])=\alpha+\cdots+\beta x+\cdots$ and $x$ is a $0,1$ variable, if you switch the coding of $x,$ that replaces $x$ by $1-x.$ Plugging that in gives $$h(E[y])=\alpha+\cdots+\beta(1-x)+\cdots=(\alpha+\beta)+\cdots-\beta x+\cdots.$$ Thus, the coefficient of $x$ is negated *and* the intercept $\alpha$ is modified (in a predictable way).

Comment: Thank you, it has been very useful for my thesis. Would you suggest any further reading for it?